# JAX-RS WebClient is Ignoring Kerberos Auth when Redirect

Tags: java, client, jax-rs, cxf, kerberos

First, I'm newbie at rest services. I'm trying to call a rest api with Kerberos Auth. There are 2 nodes at the server side. One is active and other one is in standby. When I set active node url as end point, I can perfectly call WS. But servers sometimes can redirect to other node. So I must set .setAutoRedirect() to true.

But when I do this, I got "**Error 401 Authentication required**" error.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your response.

```java
    public class KerberosAuth {

        public KerberosAuth(){

        }
        public WebClient getWClient(URI end_point) {
            WebClient wc = WebClient.create(end_point);
            KerberosAuthOutInterceptor kbInterceptor = new KerberosAuthOutInterceptor();

            AuthorizationPolicy policy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
            policy.setAuthorizationType(HttpAuthHeader.AUTH_TYPE_NEGOTIATE);
            policy.setAuthorization("KerberosClientKeyTab");

            kbInterceptor.setPolicy(policy);

            WebClient.getConfig(wc).getOutInterceptors().add(kbInterceptor);

            //This line causes problem
            WebClient.getConfig(wc).getHttpConduit().getClient()
                    .setAutoRedirect(true);

            return wc;
        }
    }
```

```java
    private YarnWrapper getYarnWrapper() {
            KerberosAuth ka = new KerberosAuth();
            WebClient wc = ka.getWClient(end_point);
            Response res = wc
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    //.acceptEncoding("gzip")
                    //.acceptLanguage("en-US")
                    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
                    .get();
            YarnWrapper yw = null;
            try {
                JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser((InputStream) res.getEntity());
                yw = parser.readValueAs(YarnWrapper.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return yw;
        }
```

Comment: 401 Http error code is UnAuthorized, it means either you are passing wrong credential or you do not have access. Check how you are passing credentials/token etc.

Comment: But when I delete this line "WebClient.getConfig(wc).getHttpConduit().getClient()
                    .setAutoRedirect(true);
" It works perfectly.